# Is Django's localflavor.ca.ca_provinces.PROVINCE_CHOICES right?

Tags: python, django

Is this right?  Why don't the tuples in PROVINCE_CHOICES have the name of the province as the second element the way that STATE_CHOICES do?

The first few elements of localflavor.ca.ca_provinces.PROVINCE_CHOICES look like this:

```
(('AB', <django.utils.functional.__proxy__ at 0x7fb581a90290>),
 ('BC', <django.utils.functional.__proxy__ at 0x7fb581a902d0>),
 ('MB', <django.utils.functional.__proxy__ at 0x7fb581a90310>),
```

But localflavor.us.us_states.STATE_CHOICES looks like I expect:

```
(('AL', 'Alabama'),
 ('AK', 'Alaska'),
 ('AS', 'American Samoa'),
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you closely observe the code for [PROVINCE_CHOICES](https://github.com/django/django-localflavor/blob/master/localflavor/ca/ca_provinces.py), it has been using:

```
from django.utils.translation import ugettext_lazy as _

PROVINCE_CHOICES = (
    ('AB', _('Alberta')),
    ('BC', _('British Columbia')),
    ('MB', _('Manitoba')),
```

Now, [ugettext_lazy](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/topics/i18n/translation/#working-with-lazy-translation-objects):

> The result of a ugettext_lazy() call can be used wherever you would
>   use a unicode string (an object with type unicode) in Python. If you
>   try to use it where a bytestring (a **str object**) is expected, things
>   will not work as expected, since a ugettext_lazy() object doesn’t know
>   how to convert itself to a bytestring.

Now, observe:

```
If you ever see output that looks like "hello
<django.utils.functional...>", you have tried to insert the result of
ugettext_lazy() into a bytestring. That’s a bug in your code.
```

If I am not wrong, the `django-localflavor` has ignored `ugettext_lazy can be used where you use a Unicode object`.

If you really want to continue with ugettext_lazy for some reason:

`ugettext_lazy("Hello").encode('utf-8')` --- Output: `'Hello'`

or I could also get the unicode of the lazy proxy to get evaluated:

`unicode(ugettext_lazy(u"Hello"))` --- Output : `u'Hello'`

**NOTE:** `ugettext_lazy` call is evaluated before the proper **locale** has been set.

Interesting reading on [`ugettext_lazy`](http://blog.bessas.me/post/65775299341/using-gettext-in-django)

Comment: Thanks.  So is that a good way to do it?  Why is it different from the way STATE_CHOICES is implemented?

Comment: Welcome, it has its own usage. Read [this](http://blog.bessas.me/post/65775299341/using-gettext-in-django). In case of STATE_CHOICES they have used direct string. Not sure the reason behind their development.